# How to avoid exceeding free Openweathermap api calls using leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openweathermap

I've created a very simple HTML page which uses Leaflet and OpenWeatherMap. I just exceeded the free 60 calls per minute limit using the OpenWeatherMap and my API key was temporarily blocked. I've updated the parameters to try and avoid this in future. Using these parameters, the OWM tile displays correctly, but will this make a difference, or am I deluded?

```
var precipitation = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openweathermap.org/map/precipitation_new/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?appid=<My OWM API key>', 
         {
          maxZoom: 18,  // do not display if zoomed beyond this level
          area: 'worldwide',  //set area to be worldwide
          updateInterval: 300000, // Restrict updates while panning to every 5 minutes
          attribution: 'Weather &copy; <a href="https://openweathermap.org">OpenWeatherMap</a>' //add attribution to leaflet attribution string
         });
```

Comment: You can inspect your page Javascript's hits to the API -- and see how many there are -- by opening your browser devtools and looking at the Network tab, so this attempt to slow the rate of hits you can test for yourself without blowing through another daily quota. And this kind of rate-limit question is often mentioned in FAQs for public APIs like the one you use.